# Add certain number of days to the already selected date (the date that is in the datepicker textbox currently)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have already looked on several questions on stackoveflow but no one seems to be answering my question.

In my application, users often need to go to +1 or -1 day from the current selected date. For this, I want to make this process more quick by adding two image buttons for +1 and -1 operation on the right side and the left side respectively.

I have tried this:

```
$('#date').datepicker('setDate', '-1');
```

But it always set the +1 date from the current date (that is today -1, not the -1 from the selected date).

How can I achieve this..??
Any help would be appreciable.

#### Tried Later:

```
function AddDays(arg) {
    var d = $('#date').datepicker('getDate');
    var d = new Date(d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay() + arg);
    $('#date').datepicker('setDate', d);
}
```

And Calling this function as `AddDays(1)` and `AddDays(-1)` on `onclick` event of `image` but It produces very strage result.
For Example if I set the current date to `25-03-13` that is in `dd-mm-y` format then clicking on -1 button is setting the date to `28-02-0-87`. Clicking it on again will result in no change. And clicking it third time will result `01-02-0-87`.

I can't get the point. What kind of behavior is this..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have written my solution. Here is the code

```
function AddDays(arg) {
    var d = $('#date').datepicker('getDate');
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + arg);
    $('#date').datepicker('setDate', d);
}
```

Where `date` is the `id` of my `jquery-ui datepicker`.

I am still looking for any inline code (single line) that I can put directly in `onclick` event of my `next` and `previous` buttons.